# Form Authentication - Listener

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-listeners

I use FORM-based authentication method in Java JSP/Servlet app. I want to "do something" after a successful login. Is there any listener which help me to do it? I don't want to put any code at the beginning of each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, authentication being a cross-cutting concern, you would have extracted it to an authentication [`ServletFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that is applied to all the servlets that need the user to be authenticated. If you have such a filter, this logic would go into that filter after successful authentication.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you very much for your answer. I set up filter on all pages to "/*" but could you tell me if it's possible to find out that previous page was "login.page" (on that form I have action set up to "j_security_check")?

Comment: Assuming that you would be using cookies to track a user session once logged in, I still think there will be only one code path, that validates the form input in the absence of cookies in the incoming request. This post-login handler code should go there.

Comment: I want to do something only once, immediately after successful login. For this I need to know that this is the first page after login. Do you think that the only way to find it out is to check some cookie? And if the cookie is not set up it will mean that this is the first page?

Comment: The cookie logic also works. I am interested in how that filter is able to know that you have to authenticate the form inputs when the user starts off.

Comment: After successful login I will have UserPrincipals, then I will do "something" and finally I will set cookie. The next call of the filter will depend on this cookie.

Comment: Then what you said in your previous comment is the way to go.

Comment: Do you think that way with filters and cookies is the best way to do it?

Comment: I am sure filter is the place to do it as that's the only place where the authentication happens the first time. As for the cookie, you should decide if the task you want to perform can be done along with "something" you mentioned even before setting the cookie or not.